# Can profile settings be upgraded?

Tags: managed-package, package, custom-profile, push-upgrade

In a custom application with two custom profiles, the profile settings were added to the package. This package was installed in a developer org. In the new version of the app (package), if we add/remove settings in profile, would those be treated as push upgrades in managed package?
For example: Adding a new object. Including this object's page layout and record type settings in custom profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to read [About Permission Sets and Profile Settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_perm_sets_profile_setttings.htm). For new permissions:

> Profile settings are applied to existing profiles in the subscriber's organization on install or upgrade. **Only permissions related to new components created as part of the install or upgrade are applied.**

(Emphasis added).

So, if you add a new component, *and* update the profile at the same time, they will be updated. Otherwise, they will not be updated, because the subscriber could have modified the profile in the interim.